# Swift: Changing the length of a ForEach loop and updating the view during use

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach

I've seen some similar questions but I'm still struggling to sort this one out. I am making a word game that involves typing a word between 4-6 letters long. The game board is generated in its own view file using a ForEach loop that currently iterates 6 times. On the 3rd round, I want to change the game board to be 7 spaces long instead of 6, and during the final round I want to make the game board 8 spaces long. Initially I tried setting the upper limit to equal the value of a variable or return value of a function and it works "in theory" but depending on what I try, either the game crashes on round 3 or the board just stays 6 spaces long.

I've included the GuessView code as it exists below

```
struct GuessView: View {
    @Binding var guess: Guess
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 3) {
            ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(guess.guessLetters[index])
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.systemBackground)
                    .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .heavy))
                    //.border(Color(.secondaryLabel))
                    .overlay(
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 3)
                            .foregroundColor(.pink),
                        alignment: .bottom
                )
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The majority of the logic exits in a Swift file that called WordDataModel. It's an Oberservable Object and essentially contains a class with all of the relevant functions and variables that I pull from. So for instance, when I was trying to make the upper limit of the ForEach loop a variable that changed I had that variable stored/changing in the WordDataModel function and had GuessView looking like this

WordDataModel:

```
var boardLength: Int = 5
```

GuessView:

```
ForEach(0...dm.boardLength, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(guess.guessLetters[index])
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
```

But when I update the value in WordDataModel or try to bring the variable over using @Binding or @State it doesn't seem to work.

Hopefully I've provided enough data, any suggestions are much appreciated thank you!

Comment: ForEach is a View not a loop, it'll crash if you use it as an index

Answer (score 1):

Use [@Published](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) for a property, it creates a publisher for type.

```
@Published var boardLength: Int
```

Comment: That might make it work, but the app is crashing on initiation of round 3. At first I thought that meant it wasn't working but now I'm noticing the fatal error is occurring when GuessView generates the Text(guess.guessLetters[index]). For some reason the index is having issues when the length is changed. (For context, manually making the board length 7 characters works so I believe the error is in the transition not the existence of an extra space).

Comment: Edit nevermind, the error once I added @Published was coming from somewhere else, I sorted it out. Thank you your solution worked!